# Parallax-like tilting of elements in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

First question here at SO so please be nice if my syntax or structure isn't great :P

Anyways, I'm building a full-page html/js app have a simple html structure with 4 divs that scale with the screen size, and are laid out in a 50/50 grid format.

I would like to have these divs tilt away from the mouse (with varying strength depending on x or y axis).

EDIT: I'm using some calculations that don't really happen to work too well:

```
var centerX = $( 'html' ).width() / 2;
var centerY = $( 'html' ).height() / 2;
var oppositeposX = event.pageX - centerX;
var oppositeposY = event.pageY - centerY;
var offset = "skew(" + oppositeposX * -.05 + "deg," + oppositeposY * .02 + "deg)";
```

^ this is the calculation I'm using to transform the content... I am sure there must be a better way to do this and achieve better results.I need it to skew the page in the opposite direction as if to focus on the mouse's direction.

EDIT #2: I've now got a nice looking tilt effect using the following!

```
$( "body" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
    var centerX = $( "body" ).width() / 2;
    var centerY = $( "body" ).height() / 2;
    var oppositeposX = event.pageX - centerX;
    var oppositeposY = event.pageY - centerY;
    var offset = "rotateY(" + -oppositeposX * .2 + "deg) rotateX(" + (1 * oppositeposY * .1) + "deg)";
    var rotate = {'transform' : offset};
    $(".container").css(rotate);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/LankyMoose/a6wu587y/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without showing your code what you have tried so far - nobody will be able to help you. Provide a minimal example which shows the problem.

Comment: @michaPau thanks for the heads up, I have updated my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the effect you are trying to achieve might be better suited to a css 3d rotation rather than a skew.

I've edited your fiddle with a few changes.

1) Setting a `perspective` on the body. This will allow the `.container` to be manipulated in 3d space.

2) Changed the `transform` rule to use `rotate` instead of `skew`.

3) I've altered the css to position the 4 items absolutely, rather than floating them. This means they will adapt to the size of whatever window they are in.

Anyway, hopefully that should give you a start towards getting the effect you want.

```js
$( "#togglelogs" ).click(function() {
  $( "#logs" ).toggle( 100, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
$( "body" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
  var pos = "Mouse Position: ";
  var centerX = $( "body" ).width() / 2;
  var centerY = $( "body" ).height() / 2;
  var oppositeposX = event.pageX - centerX;
  var oppositeposY = event.pageY - centerY;
  var offset = "rotateY(" + oppositeposX * .2 + "deg) rotateX(" + (-1 * oppositeposY * .2) + "deg)";
  var skew = {'transform' : offset};
  var oppositeskew = {'transform' : offset};
  
  pos += "x = " + event.pageX + ", " + "y = " + event.pageY;
  $( "#mouselog" ).empty();
  $( "#mouselog" ).append(pos);
  $( "#center" ).empty();
  $( "#center" ).append("Center X = " + centerX + ", Center Y = " + centerY);
  $( "#offset" ).empty();
  $( "#offset" ).append("Offest X = " + oppositeposX + ", Offest Y = " + oppositeposY);
  $(".container").css(skew);
  $( "#css" ).empty();
  $( "#css" ).append(offset);
});
```

```css
html , body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height:100%;
}

body {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#togglelogs {
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.container {
  position:absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;

}
.grid-object {
  width: calc(50% - 2px - 4px);
  height: 50%;
  margin: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #aaa;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
.grid-object + .grid-object {
  left: 50%;
}

.grid-object + .grid-object + .grid-object{
  left: 0;
  top:50%;
}

.grid-object + .grid-object + .grid-object+ .grid-object {
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;
}
#logs {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 10px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="grid-object">
     <h3>1</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-object">
     <h3>2</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-object">
     <h3>3</h3>
   </div>
    <div class="grid-object">
     <h3>4</h3>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="logs">
  <div id="mouselog"></div>
  <div id="center"></div>
  <div id="offset"></div>
  <div id="css"></div>
</div>
<div id="togglelogs">Toggle Logs</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that man! I've updated with some of your logic but swapped the way it rotates and it's now a lot closer to what I was looking for :D 

Maybe check out my JSfiddle now and see what you think? Thanks again!

Comment: No problem :) Yeah your JsFiddle is looking pretty cool now - nice work!